# JQuery HTML Avoid the first row in each table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have few tables on my site, and I am trying to write 2 functions.
First function is checking if mouse is on the row, then it set the background color of that row.
Second function is checking if mouse leave a row, then delete the background color.
But I'm trying to avoid first row each table

HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Name</td></tr>
    <tr><td>David</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Lukas</td></tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr><td>Something Else</td></tr>
    <tr><td>John</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Pedro</td></tr>
</table>
```

JQuery code:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'table tr:not(:first)', function () {
    $(this).css("background", "orange");
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'table tr:not(:first)', function () {
    $(this).css("background", "");
});
```

I have to use ".on" because second table is loaded by Ajax request.

When I enter mouse on first row of first table, nothing will happen (It's ok!) 
But when I enter on the first row of second table, it will be changed

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you achieve desired behavior using CSS only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `first-child` instead of `first`. `fisrt` selects only the first element whereas `first-child` select all first children.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'table tr:not(:first-child)', function () {
    $(this).css("background", "orange");
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', 'table tr:not(:first-child)', function () {
    $(this).css("background", "");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this CSS to achieve the desired behavior of changing backgrounds on `tr` excluding **first** one, without using JavaScript:

```
tr:not(:first-child):hover {
    background: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use thead and tbody instead.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Name</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Someone</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Someone</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Someone</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', 'table tbody tr', function....
```